# neo4j crash while delete using web client

Tags: neo4j

I have a test neo4j (2.0.3) database with about 1 milion nodes of label "B".
when im running the next command from the web client (`http://localhost:7474/browser/`):

```
MATCH (n:`B`) delete n
```

The client is crashing and also the server.
in the console.log i get the error:

```
SEVERE: The response of the WebApplicationException cannot be utilized as the response is already committed. Re-throwing to the HTTP container
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat$1.write(OutputFormat.java:174)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1506)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.StreamingJsonFormat$StreamingRepresentationFormat.flush(StreamingJsonFormat.java:401)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.StreamingJsonFormat$StreamingRepresentationFormat.complete(StreamingJsonFormat.java:389)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat$1.write(OutputFormat.java:160)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$ContentCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.flush(WebComponent.java:315)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.flush(ContainerResponse.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.flush(Utf8Generator.java:1091)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.StreamingJsonFormat$StreamingRepresentationFormat.flush(StreamingJsonFormat.java:397)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:167)
    ... 45 more
```

How can i fix it?
also, is there a formal bug database for neo4j, like oracle metalink? i wasn't able to find one.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the transaction for this grows way too large. Use

```
MATCH (n:`B`) delete n LIMIT 50000
```

and run it multiple times until all `B` nodes have been gone.

Comment: This syntax is wrong and i didnt find a way to do so in cypher.